Unexpected Execution of Sequence in WSO2 Micro Integrator
I am using WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0 and encountering an issue with my integration flow when processing HTTP requests in asynchronous mode. Below is the flow I have set up:

The request is received, and a response is sent back immediately using the clone mediator to process the request asynchronously.
In the cloned sequence, I have a sequence named common that performs the following steps:
Calls the deposite sequence.
After that, it calls the subscribe sequence.
If there is any failure in the subscribe sequence, it calls the rollback sequence.
The rollback sequence is expected to handle any failure and, using the loopback mediator, send the flow back to the outSequence.
In the outSequence, I use the call mediator to send the final response to a callback URL.
The Problem:
What I am observing now is unexpected behavior:
The response is sent back as expected after the initial request is received.
However, after the response is sent, the rollback sequence is being executed again unexpectedly.

I’m trying to understand why the rollback sequence is being triggered again, even though the response has already been sent. This behavior was not expected, and I would appreciate any insights or advice on how to resolve this issue.
